# how to query @MapKeyJoinColumn in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, dictionary, jpa-2.0, hql

my Resources entity has a property like:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "CMS_RESOURCE_USER_PERMISSION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "PERMISSION", length = 50, nullable = false)
protected Map<User, ResourcePermission> userPermissions = new HashMap<User, ResourcePermission>();
```

now I want to get Resource by User,how can I do that?any suggestion?
Thank advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPQL has the key(), entry() and value() operators for working with Maps. No doubt Criteria API has something similar if you're using that.

Looking at section 11.3.5.1 of the documnetation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

it seems you want something *like* (I haven't tried this):

```
"from resources r join r.userPermissions p where key(p) = ?1";
```

Although see the following Hibernate issue which is reported fixed in 4.1.4+:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5396